# Reduce Cypress docker image size

Tags: reactjs, docker, testing, yarnpkg, cypress

I'm running UI tests using Cypress with their docker image `cypress/browsers:node12.6.0-chrome75`. Unfortunately the size of the image is 1.276GB, which is slowing my tests down quite a bit.

Any way to reduce this, or are there smaller images available?

This is my docker file:

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node12.6.0-chrome75

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ./.npmrc /opt/app/.npmrc
COPY ./package.json /opt/app/package.json
COPY ./yarn.lock /opt/app/yarn.lock
RUN yarn

COPY . /opt/app/

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn"]
CMD ["build"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can predownload `cypress/browsers:node12.6.0-chrome75` for your test environment, then when do docker build again, it will use the local image, not try to download from internet.

If above is not what you needed, then use a slim image will be your choice, see [node12.6.0-chrome75 Dockerfile](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/blob/master/browsers/node12.6.0-chrome75/Dockerfile) & its base image [cypress/base:12.6.0 Dockerfile](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/blob/master/base/12.6.0/Dockerfile), you could find it use `node:12.6.0`, you could build your own image with `node:12.6.0-slim` which is smaller compared to `node:12.6.0`:

```
node              12.6.0-slim           2523ec7bd8fd        7 weeks ago         151MB
node              12.6.0                7c412a558705        7 weeks ago         907MB
```

After combine all dockerfiles, the final workable Dockerfile is next(NOTE: I remove the `git --version` in combined dockerfile as seems no git needed for your scenario, meanwhile `node:12.6.0-slim` not have git preinstalled):

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12.6.0-slim

## https://superuser.com/a/1423685/458816
# RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  libgtk2.0-0 \
  libgtk-3-0 \
  libnotify-dev \
  libgconf-2-4 \
  libnss3 \
  libxss1 \
  libasound2 \
  libxtst6 \
  xauth \
  xvfb \
  # install Chinese fonts
  # this list was copied from https://github.com/jim3ma/docker-leanote
  fonts-arphic-bkai00mp \
  fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp \
  fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp \
  fonts-arphic-gkai00mp \
  fonts-arphic-ukai \
  fonts-arphic-uming \
  ttf-wqy-zenhei \
  ttf-wqy-microhei \
  xfonts-wqy \
  # clean up
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm install -g npm@6.10.0
RUN npm install -g yarn@1.16.0

# a few environment variables to make NPM installs easier
# good colors for most applications
ENV TERM xterm
# avoid million NPM install messages
ENV npm_config_loglevel warn
# allow installing when the main user is root
ENV npm_config_unsafe_perm true

# versions of local tools
RUN echo  " node version:$(node -v) \n" \
  "npm version: $(npm -v) \n" \
  "yarn version:$(yarn -v) \n" \
  "debian version:  $(cat /etc/debian_version) \n" \
  "user:$(whoami) \n"

USER root

RUN node --version
RUN echo "force new chrome here"

# install Chromebrowser
RUN \
  wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update
# disabled dbus install - could not get it to install
# but tested an example project, and Chrome seems to run fine
# RUN apt-get install -y dbus-x11
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# "fake" dbus address to prevent errors
# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87
ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null

# Add zip utility - it comes in very handy
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip

# versions of local tools
RUN echo  " node version:$(node -v) \n" \
  "npm version: $(npm -v) \n" \
  "yarn version:$(yarn -v) \n" \
  "debian version:  $(cat /etc/debian_version) \n" \
  "Chrome version:  $(google-chrome --version) \n"
```

Finally, use `docker build -t cypress/browsers:custom .` to build your own image, put it to dockerhub, and your application Dockerfile could switch to use this docker image.

```
$ docker images | grep cypress/browsers
cypress/browsers     custom                15b31db2df81    About a minute ago   810MB
cypress/browsers     node12.6.0-chrome75   a029268ee2c8    8 weeks ago          1.41GB
```

Of course, you could continue reduce unnecessary packages in above Dockerfile, e.g zip, etc to continue reduce the size.